# "Duplicate" command, by default, halts operation when file already exists on destination. How to "Keep both" files instead?

Tags: applescript

```
tell application "Finder"

 set folderA to "Macintosh HD:Users:User:Downloads:A"
 set folderB to "Macintosh HD:Users:User:Downloads:B"

 duplicate every file of folder folderA to folderB without replacing

end tell
```

-- It seems that it works the first time, when there are no files yet on folderB. But the 2nd time, I get an error that files already exists. So I'm looking for the modification of my Duplicate command that keeps both files instead of halting without a prompt.

-- I want it to keep both files, or at least prompt me whether to keep both, skip, or replace.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t a combined command like that, so you would need to do it yourself.  The way the Finder works is if there is a duplicate in the destination folder, it puts up a dialog, and if you want to keep both it makes a copy, then moves/duplicates the file from the source folder, replacing the original.  The latest duplicate would be the highest numbered copy.

An example script (without the dialog) would be something like:

```
set source to "Macintosh HD:Users:User:Downloads:A:"
set destination to "Macintosh HD:Users:User:Downloads:B:" -- trailing colon for path creation

tell application "Finder" to repeat with anItem in (get files of folder source as alias list)
   try
      duplicate anItem to folder destination
   on error errmess number errnum -- oops (error -15267, etc)
      log "Error " & errnum & ": " & errmess
      set thePath to destination & name of anItem
      duplicate (thePath as alias) -- make a copy
      duplicate anItem to folder destination with replacing -- replace original
   end try
end repeat
```

Note that there is also a variety of tools (such as `rsync`, `ditto`, and `zip`) for managing archives.